# Solving a system of linear equations in Mathematica regarding the errors of different methods

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, precision-and-accuracy, number-representation

I have a system of equations, i.e.

`0.62243x + 0.51824y = 0.70524 
 0.71497x + 0.59496y = 0.80996`

I have 3 ways to solve this system (there are more but I am interested in these 3):

1. Solve the first one for x and then substitute the x at the second equation.
2. Solve the first one for y and then substitute the y at the second equation.
3. Cramer's Rule

In each case, there are 2 ways to compute the solutions:

1. Truncation (in every single step) with precision of n decimal digits
2. Roundation (in every single step) with precision of n decimal digits

For example, I solve the first equation for x and then substitute the x at the second. Using `NumberForm` I get `y=0.4000000000000674` (with precision of 16 decimal digits and truncation) and then `x={{x -> 1.39866 (0.80996 - 0.59496*0.4000000000000674}}`. However, `NumberForm` is not solving itself the system of the equations. On the other hand, using `Solve` I get `y=0.4` and `x=0.8`. So there is an error with `Solve` (Also with `NSolve`).

The questions are:

1. How can I compute the solutions for specific precision of decimal digits both with truncation and roundation for all 3 methods? Specifically, I want to compute the solutions for 5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000 and 500000 decimal digits and decide which combination (out of the 3 methods and truncation or roundation) is the best. When I say the best way, I mean the way that the solutions converge faster to the real solution as the precision increase.
2. If I had

   `ax + by = c 
   a'x + b'y = c'`

is there a way to specify a range of `a, b, c, a', b', c'` that there is no error?

3. Is there a proof that the error depends on the mantissa of the computer?

Comment: `500000` digits? You are kidding.

Comment: Why 500000 digits is a problem? Since there's a way to solve for 5 digits, then it's just a matter of time I guess

Comment: ok, so will limit the number of digits

Comment: My former comment should have read: "Nobody needs 50000 digits. The ratio between the diameter of the observable universe and the diameter of a hydrogen atom is way below 10^40. You are about to leave the domain of what is scientifically meaningful."